# Magento V2_SOAP Problem/ Error

Tags: c#, .net, soap, magento, wsdl

Before today my Magento soap worked fine, i could do a logon and a session string would be returned. I have tried the same thing today and it did not work. version 1.4.2.0

I have tried to connect to 2 different Domains, with each set up with magento and i get the same error.

Can anyone tell me why that would be?

this is the error i am getting.
{"Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ was unexpected. Expecting http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/."}

and this is the code i use with Web Reference

```
string url = "Url";
string apiUser = "User";
string apiKey = "Key";   
_magentoService = new MagentoService();
                        _magentoService.Url = url;
                        var logOn = _magentoService.login(apiUser, apiKey);
                        string logon2 = logOn.ToString();
```

The same problem with version 1.5 stable

Comment: Is there any errors showing up in apache error_log's or magento's reports/logs?  Also what do you mean by "a different website"?

Comment: Different domain, i have 2 magento websites set up exactly like on another. and both give me this error. Where will i find the apache_error_Log's? and i can't find the reports/logs? in using v1.4.2.0 magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having problems with the soap error do not use the api/v2_soap?wsdl, remove the ?wsdl so your connection should be something like this:

`http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap`
and not
`http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl`
nor
`http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1`

Reference:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/vie/viewthread/219528/
[Problem regarding consuming php web service in c# Desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062722/problem-regarding-consuming-php-web-service-in-c-desktop-application)

Comment: I can't even get started calling the Magento API via .NET. If you make progress, could you take a look at this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088459/how-to-call-the-magento-api-from-vb-net

Comment: I got same error my code sample is  MagentoService mservice = new MagentoService();
           // Mage_Api_Model_Server_Wsi_HandlerPortTypeClient mservice = new Mage_Api_Model_Server_Wsi_HandlerPortTypeClient();
            mservice.Url = "http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap";
           mservice.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
           string mlogin = mservice.login("shyam524", "pass@word1");          magento version 1.8.2